# Setting user interface for android BLE scanning project

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

The app displays the scanned BLE devices. The app screen looks like:

[image: please see the link]

**PROBLEM**

I want the screen to show a button when the app is opened and below the button should be the text box which will display scanned device.

The code snap is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "BLEScan";
private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
private Handler mHandler;
private boolean mScanning;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    if (!mScanning) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_scan:
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
        scanLeDevice(true);
        break;
    case R.id.menu_stop:
        scanLeDevice(false);
        break;
}
return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
    // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    // Initializes list view adapter.
    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
    scanLeDevice(true);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scanLeDevice(false);
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
    if (device == null) return;

}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

       // int ble_value=TypeManufacturerData.class.;
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAd;
    TextView deviceRssi;
    TextView deviceAddress;
}

class DeviceHolder {
    BluetoothDevice device;
    String additionalData;
    int rssi;

    public DeviceHolder(BluetoothDevice device, String additionalData, int rssi) {
        this.device = device;
        this.additionalData = additionalData;
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }
}
// Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private ArrayList<DeviceHolder> mLeHolders;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        mLeHolders = new ArrayList<DeviceHolder>();
        mInflator = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(DeviceHolder deviceHolder) {
        if(!mLeDevices.contains(deviceHolder.device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(deviceHolder.device);
            mLeHolders.add(deviceHolder);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
        mLeHolders.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceAd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_ad);
            viewHolder.deviceRssi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_rssi);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        DeviceHolder deviceHolder = mLeHolders.get(i);
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        viewHolder.deviceAd.setText(deviceHolder.additionalData);
        viewHolder.deviceRssi.setText("rssi: "+Integer.toString(deviceHolder.rssi));
        return view;
    }

}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        String deviceName = device.getName();
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        int byteCtr = 0;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < scanRecord.length ; ++i ) {
            if( byteCtr > 0 )
                b.append( " ");
            b.append( Integer.toHexString( ((int)scanRecord[i]) & 0xFF));
            ++byteCtr;
            if( byteCtr == 8 ) {
                Log.d( LOG_TAG, new String( b ));
                byteCtr = 0;
                b = new StringBuffer();
            }
        }
        ArrayList<AdElement> ads = AdParser.parseAdData(scanRecord);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < ads.size() ; ++i ) {
            AdElement e = ads.get(i);
            if( i > 0 )
                sb.append(" ; ");
            sb.append(e.toString());
        }
        String additionalData = new String( sb );
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "additionalData: "+additionalData);
        DeviceHolder deviceHolder = new DeviceHolder(device,additionalData,rssi);
        runOnUiThread(new DeviceAddTask( deviceHolder ) );
    }
};

class DeviceAddTask implements Runnable {
    DeviceHolder deviceHolder;

    public DeviceAddTask( DeviceHolder deviceHolder ) {
        this.deviceHolder = deviceHolder;
    }

    public void run() {
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(deviceHolder);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();            
    }
}
}
```

**The xml layout is:**
**listitem_device.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#f44336"
>

<TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/device_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/device_rssi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
```

actionbar_indeterminate_progress.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="56dp"
         android:minWidth="56dp"
android:background="#f48fb1">
<ProgressBar android:layout_width="32dp"
             android:layout_height="32dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: am I right, that you don't know how to check if app is launched for first time?

Comment: Are you using Kitkat version ?

Comment: Yes Milind. BLE is working for Kitkat and above OS version.

Comment: Er, you can use shared preferences to check if your app is opened for the first time or nah

Comment: The app has launched successfully and it is displaying the scanned devices. I want to change the UI but i am not sure what changes i have to make in the xml and java files. @Vlad Matvienko

Comment: I am using lollipop 5.1 @Milind Vyas

Comment: Ok so you want one Button OnClick of that button Will Only Scan Device other wise only show one Button Correct me if i wrong ! so For that add One Button In Your listitemdevice.xml and on that button click

Comment: mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
        scanLeDevice(true);

Comment: put this code Hope this will Helps you !